# Does flutter app erase files,data which wrote to application document directory when new launches

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to load which was written to application document directory in previous session.But It doesn't load in new session.Is there any configuration.

File was written to application documentary using file.copy method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Temporary directory**
A temporary directory (cache) that the system can clear at any time. On iOS, this corresponds to the NSCachesDirectory. On Android, this is the value that getCacheDir() returns.
**Documents directory**
A directory for the app to store files that only it can access. The system clears the directory only when the app is deleted. On iOS, this corresponds to the NSDocumentDirectory. On Android, this is the AppData directory.

This is taken directly from flutters website you can read more about it [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files)